# Set DIV height to 100% of page, not the browser window

Tags: html, css

I want to display a DIV at the bottom of my page. However using the code below, the DIV seems to be sitting at the bottom of the browser window instead of the page.

Please see the attached demo.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #CCC;
}

.main {
  background-color: #DDD;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT</div>
<div class="footer">THIS IS THE FOOTER</div>
```

Comment: Take off the `position: absolute` and `bottom`, `left`, `right`. Unneeded.

Comment: Do you want to the footer to be sticky at the bottom of the page?

Comment: Since no one has mentioned flex (even in the duplicate), I have made an example here: https://jsfiddle.net/niklasmh/yy9w6fc3/ . Flex is made for layout and is supported almost everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #CCC;
}

.main {
  background-color: #DDD;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT</div>
<div class="footer">THIS IS THE FOOTER</div>
```

Change the position to `fixed`! You should also apply some bottom margin to the main content.

Answer (score 1):

It's as easy as deleting:

```
position: absolute;
```

You could also delete `left`, `right`, `bottom`.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.footer {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #CCC;
}

.main {
  background-color: #DDD;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT</div>
<div class="footer">THIS IS THE FOOTER</div>
```

Comment: That will make it sit at the bottom of the content. It needs to sit at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @reado ... I don't know what you mean. Your code in the question has it at the bottom of the browser window. The one I have in the answer sits at the bottom of the page of content.

Comment: @reado Do you mean you want a minimum height, so that if your content isn't long enough to scroll that the footer will be at the bottom?

Answer (score 0):

Your footer div is set to absolute, so it is positioned relative to the first, non-static positioned ancestor. In this case, that would be your body tag. Since your body tag is set to 100% height, and your body tag gets its height from its ancestor, which is the html tag, and the html tag is also set to 100% height... the first non-static positioned element that the footer div will be relative to is an element that is 100% height of the browser window.

I.E. your code is not broken; that is how it works.

Unless by 'page' you mean the visible content displayed. Which would be a different question... `"How do I put a div at the bottom of my visible content, not the bottom of the page?"`

Answer (score -1):

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;

  height: 50px;
  background-color: #CCC;
}

.main {
  background-color: #DDD;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT<br>MAIN CONTENT</div>
<div class="footer">THIS IS THE FOOTER</div>
```

Comment: That's sitting at the bottom of the browser, not the page.

Comment: browser is nothing but body tag, by default body tag will be the parent of all the child elements.